# How to align three texts over the line?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, koma-script

I have

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\begin{document}
Lorem: ipsum \qquad  dolor: sit \qquad amet: 42 

\hrulefill
\end{document}
```

and get the output

[image]

How can I align the three texts horizontically over the line, like

```
| Lorem: ipsum                 dolor: sit                  amet: 42 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

where `||` are the side edges?

Comment: Replace `\qquad` with `\hfill `.

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: Not quite! that will center the dolor... between the two side but not put it in the center of the textwidth. Add more words to either end and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: @HerbSchulz: If the requirement is to horizontally center "dolor: sit"  with respect to the textwidth, you can use `\noindent\begin{tabular}{Wl{0.33\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}Wc{0.33\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}Wr{0.33\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}}
Lorem: ipsum &  dolor: sit & amet: 42 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}` instead. (Requires the `array` and `calc` packages. Does not work if text in the cells is too long.)

Comment: `\hfill` center perfectly the  middle part with respect the available inner space. To center the midle part with respect the margins you can use `\makebox[0pt][l]{Lorem: ipsum} \hfill  dolor: sit \hfill \makebox[0pt][r]{amet: 42}` ...and `\noindent`, of course.